# No Data is being returned from SQL Database using DBContext

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, bing-maps

I'm creating a system that draws routes using Bing Maps and ASP.Net. I want to store the postcodes for the stops on the route in a SQL Database and pass them over to the view using MVC.

However, querying the database doesn't return any results, even though the Database is popualted. I've used Debug.WriteLine in various parts of the code and deduced that though it's connecting to the database and querying the right table, when I initialise the DBContext in my controller, using `ToList.Count` on it shows 0.

My code is as follows:

**Controller - MapController.cs**

```
private StopsDBContext db = new StopsDBContext();

public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("***************************************************************************************");
        Debug.WriteLine("--->" + db.Stops.ToList().Count + "<---"); // this shows 0 
        Debug.WriteLine("***************************************************************************************");

        var Stops = from e in db.Stops
                    select e;

        List<Stop> Model = Stops.ToList();

        return View(Model);

    }
```

**Model - Stop.cs**

```
public class Stop
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public Stop(int iD, string name, string postcode)
    {
        ID = iD;
        Name = name;
        Postcode = postcode;
    }

    public Stop() {}
}

public class StopLists
{
    public IEnumerable<Stop> StopList { get; set; }
}

public class StopsDBContext : DbContext
{
    public StopsDBContext()
    {
        Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s); //this shows the sql queries in the console
    }
    public DbSet<Stop> Stops { get; set; }
}
```

I've passed hardcoded data into the view before doing this so I know that part's right, and since it's running the query it must be connecting to the Database, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** Updated classes following advice from Dai

Comment: Never return an `IEnumerable<T>` from a Controller Action (because your `DbContext` will be disposed before the View is rendered. While in your case you _are_ materializing it with `.ToList()` you should still type it as `List<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>` to ensure you don't return a "live" `IQueryable<T>` by mistake. As for why the list is empty, use your debugger and SSMS's Events Profiler.  The fact that ` db.Stops.ToList().Count == 0` tells me that your database is empty - so why are you expecting any data to be returned? What makes you think there _are_ any records in there?

Comment: BTW, Entity Framework doesn't support immutable entity types that use primary-constructors. You need to add a parameterless constructor to `Stop`. (Also I'm not a fan of EF's Code-first approach - If you already have a database then you should use a _Database first_ approach that generates scaffolded entity classes for you instead of you writing them by hand)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Firstly, I've now added an empty constructor to `Stop`. Secondly, I know for a fact the Database has records, I populated it when I created it and, I can see the records in the SQL Server Object Explorer. Lastly, Do you still need to use `.ToList()` to populate it into a `List<T>`? Sorry if its an obvious question, I'm still quite new to this.

Comment: Use your debugger: set a breakpoint on `return View(model)` and look at `db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` and make sure that looks correct to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the error now. Thanks to everyone that replied for your advice.

Turns out my model and my table had different fields and I didn't realise, so the DBContext was searching for fields that didn't exist. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the constructor like this way :

public StopsDBContext() : base("name=Connectionname")